# How to minimize profit but maximize weight in unbounded knapsack

Tags: php, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

How is it possible to change the algorithm of unbounded knapsack to selected items that total benefit (sum of selected items) become minimum.

**Example:**

| item | weight | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 | 13 |

also Capacity is 4, it means I should should pickup items in a way that total weight of picked up items become 4.

To minimize the value I should pickup items : 2-2

Comment: Unable to understand your question...please elaborate a bit more with some cases

Comment: I've just change the question's body.